# Magically lost files and data

Tags: javascript, git, file, filesystems

Today I came to work and saw that the commits that I've made have vanished. I had added 3-4 new files and changed 2 others at Friday evening, committed and pushed to remote.

Today I'm watching my commit history both on remote and local, for first: it's the same, for second: my last 2-3 commits simply don't exist, also with the added new files and changes.

I checked the commit history, no one has made a reverting commit, or changed anything. In short, my work is now in Thursday's state.

My file system was like this on Friday:

```
/Components
    /CheckBox
    /Radio
    ... a lot of other files
    /ReactSelect
        DemoReactSelect.js
        ReactSelect.js
```

Also a couple of files with tests.

Today it's like:

```
/Components
    /CheckBox
    /Radio
    ... a lot of other files
```

No `ReactSelect` folder with its content, no test files.

I thought I might just be making things up and tried to Ctrl+Z one of the files that were just changed, *not added* and I saw my changes coming back.

What cases of losing files do you see?

Comment: Are you sure you committed and pushed the code? Any change you just stashed the changes?

Comment: I just randomly found the reason, I actually miscommitted it on another branch and there was a little issue with git, which wouldn't allow me to push it, so I couldn't see the changes on another branch's remote. Found my changes locally, on totally different branch.

Comment: Fab. This means that you could use `cherry-pick` to move the commit to the correct branch

Comment: Thank you, will check it out asap. Didn't know about that feature.